# Show that $|C_G(u)| = 12$ by "counting involutions"

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

Let $G$ be a transitive permutation group acting on $\Omega$ such that every non-trivial element fixing some point has exactly three fixed points. Suppose $G_{\alpha} \cong A_5$ for some point stabilizer, and that $G_{\alpha}$ has non-regular orbits of length $30$, $20$ and $12$ on $\Omega \setminus \{\alpha\}$.

> Then $|C_G(u)| = 12$ for any involution $u \in G_{\alpha}$.

Why does this hold? The argument is by "counting involutions", but I do not know what this should mean?

Comment: Is action of $G$ transitive ?

Comment: @mesel: Yes, I edited the question!

Comment: From the information about the orbits of $G_\alpha$, an involution fixes exactly three points ($\alpha$ and two in the orbit of length $30$). Its centralizer in $A_5$ has order $4$, and $C_G(u)$ acts transitively on its fixed point set, so by the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem $|C_G(u)|=12$. I am not sure what "counting involutions" means here.

Comment: Why does $C_G(u)$ act transitively on $u$'s fixed point set ?

Comment: @DerekHolt I do not see transitivity of $C_G(u)$ too, I see by orbit sizes, that the other two fixed point must lie in one orbit (but I do not see that it must the one orbit of size $30$...), and so they could be mapped onto each other by some element from $G_{\alpha}$, but I do not see that we can choose this element from $C_G(u)$?

Comment: The orbit of length $30$ is the only one having stabilizer with order divisible by $2$. The fact that $C_G(u)$ is transitive on its fixed points follows from the fact that all involutions in $A_5$ are conjugate.

Comment: @DerekHolt: How is this implied? By your hint and some counting arguments I see that the involutions are in a $1$-to-$1$ relation with their two fixed points different from $\alpha$, which gives as $|C_G(u) \cap G_{\alpha}| = 4$ and the centralizer just contains involutions that every $v \ne u$ from the centralizer has to interchange the other two fixed points from $u$, but still this does not gives that $\alpha$ could be mapped onto the other fixed points by some $w \in C_G(u)$?

Comment: This is a very standard argument in permutation group theory, and I am surprised that you have not seen it before. Suppose that $\alpha,\beta \in {\rm Fix}(u)$ and let $g \in G$ with $\beta^g=\alpha$. Then $u^g$ fixes $\alpha$, so  $u^g$ is conjugate to $u$ in $G_\alpha = A_5$. Can you finish it now?

Comment: Looking at what you wrote again, you seem to have almost proved it yourself. Let $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ be the fixed points of $u$. Then you know that there is an element in $C_G(u)$ fixing $\alpha$ and interchanging $\beta,\gamma$. Similarly there is an element fixing $\beta$ and interchanging $\alpha,\gamma$, and you are done.

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes, but your standard argument is much shorter and also more general. My argument uses that the orbit specifically has size $30$ and contains all fixed points, but as I see your argument does not use this fact about the orbit size! So thank you for sharing that! I wrote up an answer and put both arguments in, maybe you want to take a look. Its appended at the end as the addition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I collect and give more details to the hints given by Derek in his comments.

First a note on $A_5$. The elements of $A_5$ are the identity, the $3$-cycles, the $5$-cycles and the double transpositions, hence double transpositions are the only involutions. By trial-and-error we see that all the $\frac{1}{2} \binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{2} = 15$ double transposition are conjugate, hence $15 = |A_5 : C_{A_5}(u)|$ for some double transposition $u$, which gives $|C_{A_5}(u)| = 4$.

In the given situation, $C_G(u)$ acts transitive on the three fixed points of $u \in G_{\alpha}$. Let $\beta$ be a fixed point different from $\alpha$, then $\beta^g = \alpha$ for some $g \in G$ and $u^g$ fixes $\alpha$, i.e. $u^g \in G_{\alpha}$. Now choose some $h \in G_{\alpha}$ such that $u^{gh} = u$. Then $\beta^{gh} = \alpha^h = \alpha$ and $gh \in C_G(u)$.

With orbit-stabilizer we have
$$
 3 = |C_G(u) : C_G(u) \cap G_{\alpha}| = |C_G(u)| / 4
$$
hence $|C_G(u)| = 12$.

Also for $u \in G_{\alpha}$ an involution, the two other fixed points lie in the orbit of size $30$, as for example suppose it would fix a point $\beta$ in the orbit of size $12$, then $u \in G_{\alpha} \cap G_{\beta}$, but $12 = |G_{\alpha} : G_{\alpha}\cap G_{\beta}|$, and hence with $|G_{\alpha}| = 60$ the two-point stabilizer is not divisible by $2$, giving $u \notin G_{\alpha}\cap G_{\beta}$.

*Just an addition*: With the last paragraph, all the $15$ involutions in $G_{\alpha}$ have at most $1 + 30$ fixed points, conversely, if $u$ fixes $\beta$ and $\gamma$, then $u^g$ fixes $\beta^g, \gamma^g$, and so if $g$ runs through all $g \in G_{\alpha}$, if for example $\beta$ lies in the orbit of size $30$, it goes through all its points, and is a fixed point of $u^g$, hence the  involutions have at least $30 + 1$ fixed points. Taken together, this gives every involution corresponds uniquely to two distinct points which it fixes (and the two fixed points corresponding to distinct involutions are all different), and each two points fixed on the orbit of size $30$ correspond to a unique involution from $G_{\alpha}$. With this observation the transitivity of $C_G(u)$ is also implied, as if $\alpha, \beta \in \mbox{Fix}(u)$ and $\alpha^g = \beta$ with $g \in G_{\alpha}$ (which could be choosen as they all lie in one orbit), then $u^g$ fixes also $\beta$ and lies in $G_{\alpha}$ as $g \in G_{\alpha}$, and this gives $u^g = u$ immediately as if $u^g \ne u$ they would have four different fixed points with the above remarks.

An argument similar as the above leads also to my conclusion in one comment, and as noted by Derek with this conclusion it also follows by noting that for $\beta \ne \alpha$ we also have $G_{\beta} \cong A_5$ as the action is transitive, and the situation is the same. Hence in the centralizer is an element fixing $\beta$ and interchanging the other two points, see the comments.